# How to add hilt and KSP in new Android studio hedgehog

Tags: android-studio, gradle, dagger-hilt

I am trying to add dagger hilt and ksp in new android studio canary in the application gradle

using

`alias(libs.plugins.hilt) apply false alias(libs.plugins.ksp) apply false`

However I keep Getting the error

Unresolved reference: hilt and

Unresolved reference: ksp

What is the correct way to add both hilt and ksp

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to share:

1. project gradle
2. app gradle
3. App module
   optionally repository and repImpl

this is my project gradle

```
`enter code here`buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.48")
        classpath("com.google.devtools.ksp:com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.plugin:1.9.20-1.0.14")
    }
}
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.20-1.0.14"
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
}
```

This is plugin is build app

```
`plugins {
id("com.android.application")
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.20-1.0.14"
id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}`
```